# Converting string representation of JavaScript array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Is there some javascript function that can take a string already formatted as an array, and casts it as an array?

```
var some_string = "[1,2,3,4]";
var some_array = castAsArray(some_string);
some_array.length // Returns 4.
```

Comment: It's valid JSON, so `var some_array = JSON.parse(some_string);`. If the actual string isn't JSON data, then a different approach will be needed.

Comment: You could use the evil eval :P

Comment: @Loktar I was thinking eval too, but then I sacrificed my car to Satan and all was well.

Comment: @Loktar - what is wrong with eval?

Comment: @DonnyP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: However if he is controlling his input, the only thing he would have to contend with is performance.

Comment: Using eval to parse JSON is like opening an envelope with a broadsword. Sure, maybe it works, but there's a different tool that's designed for the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is `JSON.parse()`. It'll take any string that represents a valid JavaScript object in [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON), and convert it to an object.

```
var some_string = "[1,2,3,4]";
var some_array = JSON.parse(some_string);
some_array.length // Returns 4.
```

Comment: Life can be simple sometimes ...

Answer (score 1):

Even eval will do the trick. Using eval, is not good practice but it is just a suggestion.

```
a="[1,2,3,4]"
b=eval(a)
```

Understand that using eval is always a bad idea (always means at most of the cases) and this is one excellent SO question and  answers discussing this.

[Eval-Don't use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: If you are going to downvote, leave a comment please. He is trying to help. @Shmiddty, it's great that you know why this is wrong, but at some point you didn't. Instead of "tsks", please explain why.

Comment: Anybody, downvoting...please try it in your console..

Comment: +1 It's a valid solution, and could be the best solution in some cases.

Comment: @Shmiddty: I am not saying to use eval...I will never recommend it..I am just saying it works and that answers OP's question in some sense.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades I didn't downvote, but just because it works, doesn't mean it's good code. Typically there is no justifiable reason to use `eval` like this. Answers should provide good code, not "suggestions"

Comment: The downvote isn't mine but it's likely because JSON.parse() is the actual way to do this, and using eval() in this case accomplishes nothing but opening you up to exploits.

Comment: Jack - can you add to your answer why "eval" is a poor choice? Just dont want future people to not notice the comments

Comment: @sphanley: That's an overreaction to `eval`. `JSON.parse` isn't *"the actual way"*. It's one if a number of different ways. The best way to do it will depend on the overall circumstance.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 may not be dangerous.. But lets look at replacing 3. a="[1,2,3,(function(){alert('XSS')})(),4]"
b=eval(a). Run that in your console.

Comment: @DonnyP: It is due to the optimization and injection attacks, the door that is opened by eval. I have attached a link to one SO question which discusses it. But, it is a dangerous tool and can sometime be beneficial if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I disagree -- I feel that if you've got a JSON string, the "actual way" to parse it into an object is the standard function which parses JSON into objects, not feeding it into a function which will blindly run any javascript code you give it.

Comment: @cookiemonster what can the OP use in IE8?

Comment: @sphanley: If it's always going to be known to be valid JSON, then sure. If not, and you know the string is secure, then there's no trouble using `eval`. For that matter, he could do `var array = string.slice(1,-1).split(",").map(Number);` in this case.

Comment: +1 because I don't blindly follow what others have said time and time again. This is what originally got us into the mess of Eval being overused in the first place.

Comment: @Loktar: `JSON.parse` will work in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: @Loktar: An interesting irony, isn't it. Good point.